# Magento 2: Upgrade issue 2.4.5 to 2.4.6 | issue with framework repo

Tags: magento-upgrade, magento-framework

While Upgrading from version 2.4.5 - 2.4.6 facing issue with

Command use for upgrade

`composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.6 -W`
[image: issue-screenshot]

error faced during upgrade

```
Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Helper/SortItems
  .php on line 44
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try upgrading with `composer require-commerce magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.6`  instead, as described in the [Official Documentation](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/implementation/perform-upgrade.html?lang=en)?

Comment: Facing same issue after resolving all the dependency Upgrade was successful but error on frontend is same

Comment: Can you try `composer dump-autoload`?